# Accessing a member of a union from a structure

Tags: c, structure, unions

I have a structure

```
typedef struct s_var_types_tag
{
    uint8_t type;
    union {
     s_t1_t t1_data;
     s_t2_t t2_data;
     s_t3_t t3_data;
    }
} s_var_types_t;
```

I have a function pointer

```
void (*xkey_to_type[MAX_TYPES])(s_x1_t *x1key, s_var_types_t *val);
```

I want to use this function pointer and utilize the type of data and call the specific pointer to it i.e

```
s_var_types_t* obj;
Suppose obj type has been set (obj->type = t1)
xkey_to_type[obj->type](x1key,obj)
```

In this function I want to set specifics of the type
If obj type is t1,I can access t1_data as though other components don't exist.

```
obj->t1_data.a =  xxx;
```

But it shows me an error saying that the

```
request for memberin something not a structure or union
```

Is something wrong?

Comment: try `(obj->t1_data).a`

Comment: @StoryTeller Should not make a difference due to same precedence with left to right associativity.

Comment: What's the type `s_t1_t`? The compiler complains that it's not a structure or a union.

Comment: Side note: I recommend you not prefix your type with `s_`. If you want it to be clear that it's a `struct`, don't `typedef` it so you write the `struct` every time. However, that's also unnecessary since it's quite impossible to mistake a `struct` for something else. At least the compiler won't make any mistakes and would catch you if you make any. Adding a lot of useless prefixes and suffixes that give information already known just makes the code less readable.

Comment: Furthermore, avoid `_t` in your types. They are reserved (by C or POSIX) for future types: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: @user694733, I don't remember precedence rules by heart. Using parenthesis (but not overusing) is useful for making sure that what I expect to happen, will happen, and also communicates it to anyone glancing at the code.

Comment: @StoryTeller, `a->b.c` happens so often that it's almost as clear as `a*b+c`. I don't remember all precedences either, but using parentheses for such real common operators both hurt your wrists typing them and others' eyes reading them. You can also understand the precedence in this case very easily, since `a->(b.c)` is absolutely meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, give your `union` a name:

```
union {
 s_t1_t t1_data;
 s_t2_t t2_data;
 s_t3_t t3_data;
} my_union;
```

Then, you can access its fields:

```
obj->my_union.t1_data.a =  xxx;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are using is called an "anonymous union". This is a new feature that appeared in C11. If you don't use that you'll have to name your union member.

```
union {
 s_t1_t t1_data;
 s_t2_t t2_data;
 s_t3_t t3_data;
} u;
```